Mixed Project Types in Preact (SSG + SPA)
I am experimenting with using the static site generation project type in Preact. It uses the Vike framework which I understand supports mixed rendering modes (e.g. SSG + SPA).
I would like to have most of the Preact site configured as SSG but then have a specific folder configured as SPA. I have tried initialising the Preact project as SSG and then changed the Vike configuration of the subfolder to SPA but that doesn't seem to work.
Are there any examples of setting up mixing rendering modes with Vike and Preact?

Are you using create-preact to generate this project? We haven't initialized projects using Vike with it for a fairly long time, and it's not necessarily the path we'd immediately recommend. Generally, we'd suggest prerendering via @preact/preset-vite, and it would probably fit this use case better. That being said, SSG is still an SPA with both Vike and @preact/preset-vite -- the only difference if if you server render the page.

I was just using npm init preact and then selecting the SSG option from the project type prompt. It then scaffolded a folder with prerendering via Vike.

You're using a very outdated version then, try npm init preact@latest. Vike was removed  8-ish months ago from that initializer.

Thanks...that did the trick! Is there something specific I should update so that I don't have to use @latest?

You can try to manually delete the module in ~/.npm/_npx or use npm cache clean --force. NPM will give a warning, but all this does is clear out the local cache so you don't have anything outdated sitting around. Obviously, with a cleared-out cache, project installs will take a bit longer.

Thanks. I ended up having to do both of those things for it to start using the latest version of create-preact by default.

Now that you're using the recommended setup for prerendering with Preact, there's two options available here, and depend on which list is bigger: the list of URLs you want to prerender, or the list of URLs you want to skip. Basic white vs blacklist situation.
// src/index.jsx
const prerenderWhitelist = ['/foo', '/bar', '/baz'];
export async function prerender(data) {
    if (!prerenderBlacklist.some(url => data.url.startsWith(url))) {
        return null;  // skips prerendering that page
    }
    ...
}

const prerenderBlacklist = ['/foo', '/bar', '/baz'];
export async function prerender(data) {
    if (prerenderBlacklist.some(url => data.url.startsWith(url))) {
        return null;  // skips prerendering that page
    }
    ...
}

You can potentially also add a list of URLs to prerender in your vite.config.js, using the prerender.additionalPrerenderRoutes option:
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import preact from "@preact/preset-vite";

const prerenderWhitelist = ['/foo', '/bar', '/baz'];

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [preact({
        prerender: {
            enabled: true,
            additionalPrerenderRoutes: prerenderWhitelist,
        }
    })]
});


One thing to note is that prerender from preact-iso (which the templates use by default) crawls your prerendered HTML, feeding relative links back into the prerenderer. For example, it'll start by prerendering /, and in the process it might find this: <a href="/second-page">Second Page</a>.  With this, it'll add /second-page to the list of pages to prerender, and prerendering will complete when all are done.
You can use renderToStringAsync from preact-render-to-string directly yourself if you don't want this crawling behavior (prerender from preact-iso is just a thin wrapper around it), but a white/blacklist setup works just fine alongside it too. Just something to be aware of if you're wondering where the links are coming from.

Thanks for much for the detailed answer...that is really useful. I think this might have been for my other question though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78899575/preact-pre-rendering-with-large-content-site

Well I meant to write this here, just to try to address your original question once we got things back on the recommended track (ergo, the SSG option from create-preact). Didn't see your question, but will answer it when I can.

Thanks for pre-empting my other question then as this was very helpful in answering that one too!
