Preact Pre-rendering With Large Content Site
The pre-rendering baked into Preact via @preact/preset-vite is awesome and really easy to get working. It automatically discovers additional URLs to pre-render as it renders each of the routes.
What's the best strategy if you have a very large content site with thousands or even tens of thousands of unique URLs? It doesn't seem practical to pre-render all of those URLs at build time as it would take far too long. Is there a way to define a boundary for the pre-rendering so that it doesn't end up traversing every URL of the entire site?
Also, how do you then handle content changes that could have a large ripple effect on the already pre-rendered pages? For example, let's say we have an article page that contains links to other related articles. A change to the title of one article could require re-rendering of multiple other articles as well as any index pages where that article is listed. It might be quite difficult to determine all of the other URLs impacted by the content change and therefore hard to know which URLs need to be re-rendered.


It doesn't seem practical to pre-render all of those URLs at build time as it would take far too long.

Prerendering/SSG only runs at build time -- if this isn't the behavior you want, prerendering might not be a good fit.
Have you ran tests to confirm this is an issue? It's pretty typical for a CI/CD runner to take a few minutes in most environments, and in a few minutes, you could render hundreds of thousands of pages with any render to string implementation, not just Preact's. If you have a performance issue, please, raise an issue as there's things we could maybe do, but I'd make sure one exists first.

Is there a way to define a boundary for the pre-rendering so that it doesn't end up traversing every URL of the entire site?

Not easily. You can pass in URLs to prerender, so theoretically you could build your own service to determine which URLs need a new render depending on the content, but that's something you'd need to build out entirely yourself. We don't support it directly.
If you did want to do this, it'd look something like this:
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import preact from "@preact/preset-vite";

// You might upload an artifact during a CI workflow
// that determines which URLs need updates, then pull
// it at build time in your config.
const prerenderUrls = await fetch(...);

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        preact({
            prerender: {
                enabled: true,
                additionalPrerenderRoutes: prerenderUrls,
            }
        })
    ]
});


No I haven't run any tests yet but I already know the complexity of some of the data retrieval needed to construct individual article pages so can foresee this taking a long time when there are lots of pages. I am exploring SSG due to concerns about SEO so it feels like a necessary option but I do worry about keeping those pre-rendered pages up to date as content changes in the CMS. So, pre-rendering also needs to happen outside of the build process...how should that be handled?

Oh...and can pre-rendering work with something like react-query to fetch data from an API?

Prerendering inherently only runs at build time -- that's what it is, runs once on deploy and only then. If you have and are happy with an SPA, you can do per-request SSR, basically, you render the first page a user requests on the server and then hand them off to an SPA to handle subsequent navigation. Obviously requires a running server instance and it'll be slower as your rendering on request (caching can help), but it's a way of ensuring always up-to-date content.

Yes, our prerendering implementation is async and can support data fetching (even supports reading files off the file system!). You need to use the "render-as-you-fetch" method, rather than fetching via a useEffect, which is better anyhow and what both the React & Preact teams strongly urge people to use. react-query likely works but I haven't tested it.

It sounds like the pre-rendering at build time is not what I need as there will always be dynamic content needed from a database or CMS so build-time static content is never going to cut it. I'm struggling to think of a use-case where build time static content pages will ever be suitable actually...how are you seeing this used in the real world?

I tested the build with pre-rendering enabled and it gave me a fetch error when trying to access the API to retrieve the data for pre-rendering. Maybe I have misunderstood how this is supposed to work. My test pages make standard API calls via fetch or axios...can these be called during pre-rendering?

I think this is getting fairly off topic; there's a lot of great articles out there on what prerendering is and what it offers. However, prerendering doesn't mean you're locked into static content, just that the HTML is statically generated on build. You can prerender an app and have it update on the client, this isn't an issue. The Preact doc site is prerendered via this methodology, which is rebuilt & redeployed every time we update the markdown content. However, we also show the current version of Preact in the header which is dynamic & updated client side, if the static is out-of-date.

Sorry, but "it gave me a fetch error" isn't much to go on. Yes, you can make standard fetch calls, obviously whatever server is supposed to reply to that needs to be running, but it's fully supported. This example fetches a local file, rather than from a remote URL, but shows a suspense-based fetch impl: https://github.com/preactjs/preset-vite/blob/main/demo/src/components/LocalFetch.tsx

Happy to talk through any questions you have, but Stack isn't necessarily the best place for long discussions like this that have nuance. @preact/preset-vite's GitHub repo or the Preact Slack are perhaps better options.

The fetch error was because query parameters were being passed into the page but those didn't seem to be coming across with the pre-rendering at build time. I will move the discussion across to the slack channel.
